# Can I re-use my friend's Diablo III license key?

Tags: diablo-iii

For example, he registered the license key to his Battlenet account. My question is, can i use his code in order to activate my Diablo 3?

Answer (score 5):

No, you must purchase your own license to activate the game on your Battle.Net account.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. Each code is only good for one account. And each account can only be logged into one place at a time for each game.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your account is not against ToS.

*****Never give out your account information.

Sharing your account information with a family member, friend, or another player is an easy way to lose control of who has access to your account and increase the risk of compromise -- no matter how well you might know the person you’re sharing your login information with. Keep in mind that even if you practice optimum Internet security at home, you can't control how another person will make use of your account information…or how secure their own computer system might be.*****

There is nothing about bans or whatever.

Source: http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/224741-battlenet-and-diablo-iii-account-security/

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use his code in your account (obviously), but you *can* use his account if he's willing to give you his password **and** doesn't want to play at the same time as you.

Of course sharing accounts is against the battlenet TOS, so theoretically Blizzard could ban you for doing so.

Comment: How come this one is downvoted? The answer it perfectly true, etically wrong or not.

Comment: Probably some of those "TOS should be followed now matter how stupid" people...

Comment: @mmmattias Gaming.SE promotes an ethic behavior and is against piracy or other improper behaviors.

Comment: Sharing is not piracy/improper behaviour. You could do that with an offline game, too - and in this case you don't even play at the same time.